# I can't get current location - api is either deprecated or too new

Tags: android, deprecated, locationmanager

I' m coding an app with minSdk set to 23 and targetSdk and compileSdk set to 30.

My goal is to get current device location (not the lastKnownLocation). The problem is: I can either use `LocationManager::getCurrentLocation()` which requires api level 30 or `LocationManger::requestSingleUpdate` which is deprecated since api 30 and it's blocking me from compiling the app.

I'm not sure what am I supposed to do in this situation to not drop any version support. Sorry if this is newbie question, I'm not very experienced in android development

Comment: "and it's blocking me from compiling the app" -- deprecation does not block builds normally. What do you mean by "blocking me from compiling the app"?

Answer (score 3):

You just do

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        // Use getCurrentLocation
    }else{
        // Use requestSingleUpdate
    }
```

Or better yet use the the [Fused Location API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates) from Google Play Services and not worry about it.

Also a deprecated api does not prevent you from compiling